# Place icon on same line as text

Tags: flexbox, react-native

I'm trying to place my icon on the same line as `2 Replies`.

Here's a screenshot of how it looks:

[image]

I'd like to have it to the right of the line, as the arrow shows.

Here's how my Component's `render` function looks:

```
  render: function() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onSelect}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image source={{uri: this.state.image}}
                 style={styles.image} />
          <View style={styles.postDetailsContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.postTitle}>
              {this.state.name}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.postDetailsLine}>
              {this.state.comment}
            </Text>
            <View>
            <Text style={styles.postChildrenDetails}>
              {this.props.comment.child_comments_count} Replies
            </Text>
            <Icon
              name='fontawesome|comments-o'
              size={25}
              color='#D6573D'
              style={styles.icon}
            />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.separator} />
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      )
  }
```

Here's how my StyleSheet looks:

```
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFD',
  },
  image: {
    height: 48,
    width: 48,
    borderRadius: 25,
    marginTop: 10,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginRight: 15,
    marginLeft: 15
  },
  postDetailsContainer:{
    flex: 1,
  },
  postTitle: {
    fontSize: 15,
    textAlign: 'left',
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 4,
    marginRight: 10,
    color: '#D6573D'
  },
  postDetailsLine: {
    fontSize: 12,
    marginRight: 10,
    color: 'gray',
  },
  postChildrenDetails: {
    fontSize: 12,
    marginTop: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    color: 'gray',
    textAlign: 'right',
    flex: 1
  },
  separator: {
    height: 0.5,
    backgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
  },
  icon: {
    flex: 1,
    textAlign: 'right',
    width: 25,
    height: 25
  }
})
```

Comment: You could [:after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter) in your css. Whatever class/id your '2 replies' container has you can add the psuedo-element like this `twoRepliesContainer:after{background-image:url('chat-image.png');}

Comment: React Native StyleSheet does not support CSS pseudo-elements.

Comment: Just wrap the icon and the replies text in another view then use flexbox to style that view

Comment: What did you end up with? Trying to do something similar now.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same challenge and for anyone having the same issue, here is how I went about solving it.

Wrap the Icon and the Text in a View like @Colin Ramsey said above in the comments

It will look like this:

`<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
    <Icon name="ios-chat" size={20} />
    <Text>
      2 replies
    </Text>
 </View>`

Shalom!

Answer (score 2):

**TRY THIS**

<View
style={{
backgroundColor: "#ffc8cc",
borderRadius: 30,
margin: 5,
flexDirection: "row",
justifyContent: "space-between",
alignItems: "center",
paddingRight : 25

```
    }}
  >
    <Text style={styles.title}>Leagues</Text>
    <MaterialIcons name="sports-baseball" size={26} color="#cd000f" />
  </View>
```

css for title :

title: {
fontSize: 18,
margin: 20,
color: "#cd000f",
},

Comment: Why OP should try this?

Answer (score 0):

Center image and text same line in props reactjs

```
    <div style={{ alignItems: "center", display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }} >
    <img src={this.props.location.state.image} style={{ height: "100px", width: "100px", border: "4px solid white", verticalAlign: 'middle' }} />
 <span style={{ fontSize: '40px', fontWeight: 'bolder', textAlign: 'center', verticalAlign: 'middle' }}>
  {this.props.location.state.subject}</span>
   </div>
```